# Webelement.Click() - Getting exception on Webelement.Click() though it clicks the Element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, selenium-iedriver

### Meta

OS:  Windows
Selenium Version:  2.53.1.0
IDE: Visual Studio 2013
Browser:  Internet Explorer 11 version 11.420

I am getting an exception when i tried to click an element on webpage. This happens when a link is clicked and it opens a dialog. Webelement.click() function clicks the element and the modal dialog is opened but Click() takes time to return and finally logs exception as '**The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL "" timed out after 60 seconds.'**

### Expected Behavior:

> It should click the "Firefox Beta" download button and "IE tool bar" with RUN and SAVE option will appear

### Actual Behavior:

> It clicks the "Firefox Beta" download button and "IE tool bar" is coming. **But downloadElement.Click() waits for 60 seconds and throws exception**.

### Steps to reproduce:

**Below is code snippet:**

```
string url = "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#beta";
try{
   IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);    
   Thread.Sleep(5000);    
   IWebElement downloadElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='download-button-desktop-beta']/ul/li/a/strong"));    
   Thread.Sleep(5000);    
   downloadElement.Click();   
  }catch{
     //catch block
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this xpath instead of that.

```
IWebElement downloadElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/section[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/strong"));
```

Sometimes their is some problems with IE11 selenium is not able to work as expected. so i use double click instead of click in certain scenarios.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/section[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/strong"))).doubleClick().perform();
```

try using both, hope it will helps

Comment: Thanks Anuraj.. Second option did the help. :)

Comment: @Aniruddhya, always happy to help. :-) vote the answer, it will helpul to others also

Answer (score 0):

You can add implicit wait after downloadElement.Click() and wait for modal dialog to load completely.

Comment: you can add implicit wait statement as shown below: 
downloadElement.Click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Or
downloadElement.Click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drv,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.....path of dialod box));

Or
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) !=null);

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me -

```
package sbps;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class cvs_signup
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#beta";
        try{
           WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
           driver.get(url);
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           WebElement downloadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-beta-stub&os=win&lang=en-US'])[last()]"));
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           downloadElement.click();
          }catch(Exception e){
             //catch block
          }
        }
}
```